# as3 symbol variables not initialized yet

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, initialization, symbols

I'm initializing symbols in my timeline, and trying to access the variables within those symbols, but they return 0 or undefined even though I set the variables in the symbol's timeline. For some reason the variables haven't been set yet, though the main timeline can see that they exist. How do I make the program wait until the variables have been set?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you're putting code inside symbols, you may as well be putting code in external .as Classes. It's a much more flexible way of developing. When you create an instance of a Class, you have complete control of how it's variables are initialised. Sorry, but I'd avoid using the timeline as soon as you are able to.

Comment: we have to use timelines for the course projects

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to work with classes, not coding in timeline and frames of MovieClip.
I assume you have MovieClip from designer and you want inject some logic to the specific frame. There are many options.

**Events**

You can trigger event in the specific frame, and you work in normal way (with classes and class members).

```
//Frame code
import flash.events.Event;

this.dispatchEvent(new Event("IntroDidFinish", true, true));
stop();

//Somewhere in class
myContainer.addEventListener("IntroDidFinish", onIntroFinish, false, 0, true);

function onIntroFinish(e: Event):void{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Events help you decouple logic from the design(predefined complex MovieClip, etc.)

**Waiting for initialisation**

As MovieClip reaches some frame, you should wait extra time for initialisation. Thats why 99.9% of AS3 developers don't like MovieClip as holder for any critical data or logic. It means if you call `myMovieClip.goToAndStop(8);` you can't get `myMovieClip.someValue` declared in `8` frame after goTo operation. If you still want to go with such approach, easiest solution for you will be `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, after goTo subscribe for ENTER_FRAME event, for only one update, and do your work ;)

Comment: We don't use classes in my as3 course. How can i implement this in the timeline?